# Is metal casing always recommended/expected for audio devices (for EMI protection)?

Tags: audio, shielding

I am considering using a wooden enclosure for several homemade audio devices such as DI boxes and isolation transformers but I know that most all commercial products use metal casing. I have noted, however, when taking some of these commercial devices apart that they dont even properly ground the chassis to effectively use the metal casing as an EMI shield. I was also considering just shielding certain components such as transformers for the device and leaving the rest bare. I also was going to try and conduct some tests to compare my wooden enclosure device with commercially available metal enclosures and go from there. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, a conductive housing is always better for EMI protection. BUT: In case there are no nearby radiators that could compromise your device, it doesn‘t matter if you have a shielding or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first radio came in a plastic package, but audio circuits are sensitive to pulse noise currents such as the diode cap pulse current, which are often snubbed with 100 pf to reduce the bandwidth of the noise buzz.

Mostly noise is conducted rather than radiated.
from shared common ground currents and supply ripple as the stray capacitance in Class AB amps is not enough to pickup radiated noise.

SMPS are a different case. (Pun intended)

However there is opportunity for a poor layout to pickup current loops from the supply and return into high impedance loops.

By first experience of high powered vacuum tube power amps with no shields, left me with a great impression with very low noise, and crisp audio with booming Rock music in the late 60’s.

My advise is follow the layout practises for wiring of each section with small current loop areas and high quality caps and you should expect great results.  Allow for proper ventilation with a screened vent on top.